# what does the term rep-invariant and rep ok means?

Tags: abstraction

I heard this a lot when talking about software engineering and abstract data types, what does this do? Can anyone give me a concrete example of this concept?

Comment: Visceral reaction is to say rep means representation (and this is used in theoretical computer science often, especially with kolmogorov complexity -- look up "universal computer" if you are interested) but you need to give more context.

Comment: Well what if someone asks what is the rep-invariant of a Deck class?

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more specific.  In this case, rep invariance refers to a set of assumptions about the representation of the deck class.  For example, maybe it must contain a set of cards ...

Comment: Yes that is one I had in mind actually.. I am just confused from this on how to represent the abstraction function for a Deck of cards

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A representation invariant is a condition concerning the state of an object. The condition can always be assumed to be true for a given object, and operations are required not to violate it.

In a Deck class, a representation invariant might be that there are always 52 Cards in the deck. A shuffle() operation is thus guaranteed not to drop any cards on the floor. Which in turn means that someone calling shuffle(), or indeed any other operation, does not need to check the number of cards before and after: they are guaranteed that it will always be 52.